# Where is the history of "Go to Folder..."(in Go menu of Finder) located?

Tags: macos, finder

I just searched for a folder with that tool and now I want the 'history' of it cleared. I mean, I don't want it to show the last place(folder) I've gone by that thing.
I tried Relaunching Finder while that window (that asks to enter an address) was open, it worked but only once. Now it doesn't work.(I did this on 10.7 and worked, but it didn't work on 10.8, 10.9 and 10.10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location shown for the **Go to Folder...** command in **Finder** is stored in the `$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` file in the `GoToField` *key*. To remove it, use the following *command* in **Terminal**:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder GoToField; killall Finder
```

Comment: That command didn't work for me so I opened the plist in Xcode and deleted the entries under GoToFIeld.

Comment: @Ash, Sorry it didn't work for you however the information presented in my answer is factually correct and is still working in every release of OS X I've used it in including macOS 10.12.3. Did you copy and paste the command from my answer or manually type it and did you get any error message?

Comment: Not disputing that fact, hence the comment which does the same thing but via the UI. Hopefully someone else will find it useful.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me to delete the "Go to..." history in Sierra:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder GoToFieldHistory; killall Finder
```

This history key (which contains more than just the last targeted folder) was introduced in Sierra and doesn't exist in older system versions.